# No matching signature for aggregate function SUM for argument types: STRING

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to get some data from big query.

```
SELECT District_Council_District, SUM(Number_of_People)
FROM `absolute-vertex-356001.Opendata2.diff age male polulation distibution
HAVING District_Council_District
```

After I run the query, the error show up.

> No matching signature for aggregate function SUM for argument types: STRING. Supported signatures: SUM(INT64); SUM(FLOAT64); SUM(NUMERIC); SUM(BIGNUMERIC); SUM(INTERVAL) at [1:35]

But the data type is integer, so I don't know why would this error occur.

```
District Council District          Number of People
Central and Western District           3 748
Central and Western District           4 170
```

I have seached for the solution from google cloud perform, but their example is also simple query to use aggregate function just like me.

Comment: If the “number of people” data exists as you’ve shown it then it can’t be an integer as it has a space in it. Please update your question with the table definition

Comment: ...and then after you resolve the problem that @NickW pointed out, you'll need to fix your confusion over the function of the Group By clause vs. the Having clause.

Comment: The column `Number_of_People` is string and contains a number, but with extra spaces. First all spaces have to be removed by using `replace`. Then the string has to be converted to a number.  `select  sum(cast(replace(Number_of_People," ","") as int64))
  from unnest(["3 748","4 170"]) Number_of_People`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand the requirement of `having` clause in your query. However as mentioned in the comments you're getting this error because the `Number_of _People` column is string type(because of the presence of " ").

For instance you can try your query similar to this:

```
with t as( select "a" as name,'12 4' number union all
           select 'b','12 5' union all
           select 'a', '345 ' ) select name, sum(cast(replace(t.number, " ", "") as int64)) from t group by name
```